# Recommendation letter; reminder email

Tags: mathematics, recommendation-letter, faculty-application, interview

I had an interview for a faculty position about 6 days ago. I was asked to arrange two letters of recommendations. One of my references sent it, but another one has not submitted  yet. Shall I remind my reference to submit the letter? Or it is better to wait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send a reminder only if there is a hard deadline for its receipt. A week is very short for an expectation of a recommendation letter. If the academic schedule is anything like that of the US with December finals followed by a couple of weeks of holidays, then it is especially short. The recommender has other things on their mind and may even be away.

I expect that the institution will understand all of this and not expect quick turn-around at this time. They are probably not making decisions at this moment, in any case, if such is the academic calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Also think if that recommender is willing to submit letter or not and think carefully about potential reason behind not submitting the letter. If reviewer sees that you are better fit for the position, they would respond much sooner to the request. I am not saying this might be the reason. But this is important to consider. I have faced similar situations in the past and haven’t received letter from one of the recommender yet. Thinking about the reasons more deeply, they might be passively refusing to support.